# How to autofill column in excel?

Tags: excel, autofill

I need to change column auto.
Fo example I need fill row  a2 , a3,a4,...,zz with column value a1 , b1 , c1,...,zz.
In excel autofill rows.but I don't know about autofill column.
Is it possible with functions?
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to `TRANSPOSE` data?

Comment: No.  do like this: ='sheet1'!f$3 , ='sheet1'!g$3. ... to ='sheet1'!zz$3 ....

Answer (score 0):

You question is not so clear. If you want to obtain values from `A1`, `B1`, `C1.....` and so on then you can use `INDIRECT()` function like below.

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(ROW()+63)&"1")
```

You can also use `INDEX()` function to obtain values from row.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,1,ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

And if you want to just display `A1`, `B1`, `C1......` then use

```
=CHAR(ROW()+63)&1
```

Comment: How can do like this: ='sheet1'!f$3 ,  ='sheet1'!g$3. ... to ='sheet1'!zz$3 .

Comment: Then use formula like `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&CHAR(ROW()+63)&"1")`